# Return Similarity Matrix From Two Variable-length Arrays of Strings (scipy option?)

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, distance, levenshtein-distance

Say I have two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array(['faucet', 'faucets', 'bath', 'parts', 'bathroom'])
arr2 = np.array(['faucett', 'faucetd', 'bth', 'kichen'])
```

and I want to compute the similarity of the strings in `arr2` to the strings in `arr1`.

`arr1` is an array of correctly spelled words.

`arr2` is an array of words not recognized in a dictionary of words.

I want to return a matrix which will then be turned into a pandas DataFrame.

My current solution ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452724/string-distance-matrix-in-python-using-pdist)):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from Levenshtein import ratio
arr3 = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2)).reshape(-1,1)
matrix = squareform(pdist(arr3, lambda x,y: ratio(x[0], y[0])))
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=arr3.ravel(), columns=arr3.ravel())
```

Output:

```
            faucet   faucets      bath     parts  bathroom   faucett  \
faucet    0.000000  0.923077  0.400000  0.363636  0.285714  0.923077   
faucets   0.923077  0.000000  0.363636  0.500000  0.266667  0.857143   
bath      0.400000  0.363636  0.000000  0.444444  0.666667  0.363636   
parts     0.363636  0.500000  0.444444  0.000000  0.307692  0.333333   
bathroom  0.285714  0.266667  0.666667  0.307692  0.000000  0.266667   
faucett   0.923077  0.857143  0.363636  0.333333  0.266667  0.000000   
faucetd   0.923077  0.857143  0.363636  0.333333  0.266667  0.857143   
bth       0.222222  0.200000  0.857143  0.250000  0.545455  0.200000   
kichen    0.333333  0.307692  0.200000  0.000000  0.142857  0.307692   

           faucetd       bth    kichen  
faucet    0.923077  0.222222  0.333333  
faucets   0.857143  0.200000  0.307692  
bath      0.363636  0.857143  0.200000  
parts     0.333333  0.250000  0.000000  
bathroom  0.266667  0.545455  0.142857  
faucett   0.857143  0.200000  0.307692  
faucetd   0.000000  0.200000  0.307692  
bth       0.200000  0.000000  0.222222  
kichen    0.307692  0.222222  0.000000
```

**The problem with this solution**:
I waste time computing pairwise distance ratios on words I already know are correctly spelled.

What I'd like is to hand a function `arr1` and `arr2` (which can be different lengths!) and output a matrix (not necessarily square) with the ratios.

The result would look like this (without the computational overhead):

```
>>> df.drop(index=arr1, columns=arr2)

           faucet   faucets      bath     parts  bathroom
faucett  0.923077  0.857143  0.363636  0.333333  0.266667
faucetd  0.923077  0.857143  0.363636  0.333333  0.266667
bth      0.222222  0.200000  0.857143  0.250000  0.545455
kichen   0.333333  0.307692  0.200000  0.000000  0.142857
```

Comment: Use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) (rather than `pdist`) and give it the two arrays separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from Levenshtein import ratio

arr1 = np.array(['faucet', 'faucets', 'bath', 'parts', 'bathroom'])
arr2 = np.array(['faucett', 'faucetd', 'bth', 'kichen'])

matrix = cdist(arr2.reshape(-1, 1), arr1.reshape(-1, 1), lambda x, y: ratio(x[0], y[0]))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=matrix, index=arr2, columns=arr1)
```

Result:

```
           faucet   faucets      bath     parts  bathroom
faucett  0.923077  0.857143  0.363636  0.333333  0.266667
faucetd  0.923077  0.857143  0.363636  0.333333  0.266667
bth      0.222222  0.200000  0.857143  0.250000  0.545455
kichen   0.333333  0.307692  0.200000  0.000000  0.142857
```

Comment: When I read the documentation on cdist, I couldn't figure it out. And didn't know the arrays could be variable length. Thanks for your help!