# calculate hamming distance over dataframe coulmn values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new dataframe which is a distance matrix of all hamming distances between values of a specific coulmn in existing dataframe.
The hamming distance seems to work fine:

```
def hamming_dist(str1, str2):
    hamming = 0
    for letter in range(len(str1)):
            if str1[letter] != str2[letter]:
                hamming += 1
    return hamming

hamming_dist("hello", "heLLo")
```

Output

```
2
```

I want to compute the hamming for all values in df called hamming_df in coulmn called "protein".

```
hamming_distance_df = pd.DataFrame(hamming_dist(hamming_df["protein"], hamming_df["protein"]))\
    (index = hamming_df["protein"], columns=hamming_df["protein"])
```

The output is dataframe with correct indexes and columns, but all the values are 0 and not the actual hamming distance. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are passing pandas Series to `hamming_dist` and not strings.

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37428973/4800086

Comment: What happens if two strings have a different length? like `'Hel'` and `'HeLLOO'`? Or two strings always have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing pandas Series to `hamming_dist` and not strings. One solution is to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the pairs of strings:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product


def hamming_dist(str1, str2):
    hamming = 0
    for letter in range(len(str1)):
        if str1[letter] != str2[letter]:
            hamming += 1
    return hamming


hamming_df = pd.DataFrame(["hello", "yello"], columns=["protein"])

res = pd.DataFrame([hamming_dist(*p) for p in product(hamming_df["protein"], repeat=2)], columns=["hamming_protein"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  hamming_protein
0                0
1                1
2                1
3                0
```

An alternative is to use [`scipy.spatial.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to compute the distances:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

hamming_df = pd.DataFrame(["hello", "yello"], columns=["protein"])
arr = squareform(pdist(hamming_df["protein"].to_numpy().reshape((-1, 1)), metric=hamming_dist)).flatten()
res = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["hamming_protein"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   hamming_protein
0              0.0
1              1.0
2              1.0
3              0.0
```

**Note**

I suggest you use the following hamming_dist function that will work for strings of different length:

```
def hamming_dist(str1, str2):
    return sum(l1 != l2 for l1, l2 in zip(str1, str2)) + abs(len(str1) - len(str2))
```

**UPDATE**

If the output is a distance matrix, I suggest you use `pdist` as follows:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

hamming_df = pd.DataFrame(["hello", "yello"], columns=["protein"])
arr = squareform(pdist(hamming_df["protein"].to_numpy().reshape((-1, 1)), metric=hamming_dist))
res = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=hamming_df["protein"], index=hamming_df["protein"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
protein  hello  yello
protein              
hello      0.0    1.0
yello      1.0    0.0
```

Comment: Thank you! whay Im actually looking for is a dataframe with all my "proteins" both as indexes and coulmns names, and the values inside are the distance (so the diagonal will be 0).

Comment: @abc_123 See the update